# pygame transparency alpha issue, and pygame scale issue

Tags: python, pygame

for this code im trying to make a class that can take a png with one immage, or a png with many frames of an animation and put it on screen. most of the functionality works but there are a few bugs and i have no idea what is causing them.

in the class it initializes the information.

it creates a clear surface, puts the entire png on it to use later.
then it creates a clear surface the size of one frame, which is used in the rendering function to get the right area of the png when its needed.

then each frame of the pygame window it loads the images using a class function. right now it does not run the function that iterates through animation frames it only renders the one immage.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

screenwidth = 1000
screenheight = 500
fps = 32
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth,screenheight))
screen.convert_alpha()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class sprite():
    def __init__(self,
                 position = (0,0),#top left
                 frames = 1,
                 finalsize = (100,100),
                 pngname="missing.png",
                 startingframe = 1):
        self.position = position
        self.frames = frames
        self.finalsize = finalsize
        self.pngname = pngname
        self.currentframe = startingframe
        
        self.immage = pygame.image.load(self.pngname)#this loads a surface
        self.immage.convert_alpha()
        #dimentions defined, self.framesurface
        #transparency

        totalwidth = self.immage.get_width()
        self.frameheight = self.immage.get_height()
        self.framewidth = totalwidth/self.frames 
        self.framesurface = pygame.Surface((self.framewidth,self.frameheight))#makes surface with frame dimentions
        self.framesurface.convert_alpha()
        self.framesurface.fill((0,0,0,255))
        
        clear_surface = pygame.Surface((totalwidth,self.frameheight))
        clear_surface.convert_alpha()
        clear_surface.fill((100,100,100,255))#transparent surface made

        #clear_surface.set_alpha(0) this turns the entire immage transparent
        clear_surface.blit(self.immage,(0,0),(0,0,finalsize[0],finalsize[1]))
        self.immage = clear_surface

        #self.immage
        #self.framesurface 
        
        
                                        
        
    def frame_render(self):
        self.framesurface.blit(self.immage,
                                        (0,0),
                                        (0, self.framewidth*self.currentframe, self.framewidth, self.frameheight))
        #blits one frame
        #self.immage = self.framesurface
        
        self.framesurface = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.framesurface,self.finalsize)#scales immage to finalsize
        self.framesurface.fill((255,255,255,255))#this makes it work????
        screen.blit(self.immage,self.position,(0,0,self.finalsize[0],self.finalsize[1]))#adds it to screen

    def frame_incriment(self,speed= 1):#this function is not used as of this moment

        self.currentframe = int((((animationcounter%fps)+1)/fps)*self.frame*speed)
        if self.currentframe == 0:
            self.currentframe = self.frame
        
            
   
test = sprite()
apple = sprite(pngname = "apple small.png",position = (150,150))
banana = sprite()
activesprites = [apple,banana]

animationcounter = 0
animationloopreset_frames = fps*5 #every 5 seconds the animation counter resets
while True:
    clock.tick(fps)
    animationcounter = animationcounter + 1
    if animationcounter > animationloopreset_frames:
        animationcounter = 1
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()#shuts pygame
            exit()#ends code
        #pygame events here, buttons change activesprites

    screen.fill((255,255,255))#clears screen, place things after
    #for item in activesprites:
        #print("drawing sprite:" + item)
    test.frame_render()
    apple.frame_render()
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image: this is used as sprite textures]
[image: this is used as sprite textures]

but what I'm getting is
[image: pygame resultant window from my code]

which shows a grey surface behind the apple. it should be transparent because of the line "clear_surface.fill((100,100,100,255))" in the init function.

and the apple is cropped to 100x100, this happens on the line "self.framesurface = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.framesurface,self.finalsize)" because the scale function is making the surface 100x100 and not effecting the image for some reason even though that's the entire point of a scale function.
ive looked through the documentation of pygame and alternate ways of transparency seem a lot more complex or remove a color entirely which i don't want in this code, and i havent seen a scale alternative fixes my issue.

Comment: The problem in your code is `totalwidth, self.finalsize[1]` this should be **`totalwidth, self.frameheight`** as in the code in my answer. Stop updating the question with your new code. That makes the answer useless. I've added the complete and working example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

> ```py
> self.framesurface = pygame.Surface((self.framewidth,self.frameheight))
> self.framesurface.convert_alpha()
> ```

creates a surface in RGB format and converts it to a surface in RGBA format. Therefore the surface is completely opaque and the value of all pixels is (0, 0, 0, **1**).

You have to create a surface with RGBA format using the [`SRCALPHA`]:

```py
self.framesurface = pygame.Surface((self.framewidth, self.frameheight), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

`blit` the complete `image` on `clear_surface` not just a part of it.

```py
clear_surface = pygame.Surface((totalwidth, self.frameheight), pygame.SRCALPHA)
clear_surface.blit(self.immage, (0, 0), (0, 0, totalwidth, self.frameheight))
```

In this case the surface is completely transparent and the initial value of the pixels is (0, 0, 0, **0**):

Furthermore you need to `blit` the scaled surface on surface with the size of the original image, before you can scale it. You have to create a surface with the size of the original image in every frame. After that you can scale that surface:

```py
def frame_render(self):
    self.framesurface = pygame.Surface((self.framewidth, self.frameheight), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    self.framesurface.blit(
        self.immage, (0, 0),
        (0, self.framewidth*(self.currentframe-1), self.framewidth, self.frameheight))
    self.framesurface = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.framesurface, self.finalsize) 
    screen.blit(self.framesurface, self.position)
```

---

Complete and working example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

screenwidth = 1000
screenheight = 500
fps = 32
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth,screenheight))
screen.convert_alpha()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class sprite():
    def __init__(self,
                 position = (0,0),#top left
                 frames = 1,
                 finalsize = (100,100),
                 pngname="missing.png",
                 startingframe = 1):
        self.position = position
        self.frames = frames
        self.finalsize = finalsize
        self.pngname = pngname
        self.currentframe = startingframe
        
        self.immage = pygame.image.load(self.pngname)
        self.immage.convert_alpha()

        totalwidth = self.immage.get_width()
        self.frameheight = self.immage.get_height()
        self.framewidth = totalwidth/self.frames 
        self.framesurface = pygame.Surface((self.framewidth, self.frameheight), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        
        clear_surface = pygame.Surface((totalwidth, self.frameheight), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        clear_surface.blit(self.immage, (0, 0), (0, 0, totalwidth, self.frameheight))
        self.immage = clear_surface                  
        
    def frame_render(self):
        self.framesurface = pygame.Surface((self.framewidth, self.frameheight), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.framesurface.blit(
            self.immage, (0, 0),
            (0, self.framewidth*(self.currentframe-1), self.framewidth, self.frameheight))
        self.framesurface = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.framesurface, self.finalsize) 
        screen.blit(self.framesurface, self.position)

    def frame_incriment(self,speed= 1):#this function is not used as of this moment

        self.currentframe = int((((animationcounter%fps)+1)/fps)*self.frame*speed)
        if self.currentframe == 0:
            self.currentframe = self.frame
        
            
test = sprite() 
apple = sprite(pngname = "apple small.png",position = (150,150))
banana = sprite()
activesprites = [apple,banana]

animationcounter = 0
animationloopreset_frames = fps*5 #every 5 seconds the animation counter resets
while True:
    clock.tick(fps)
    animationcounter = animationcounter + 1
    if animationcounter > animationloopreset_frames:
        animationcounter = 1
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()#shuts pygame
            exit()#ends code
        #pygame events here, buttons change activesprites

    screen.fill((255,255,255))#clears screen, place things after
    #for item in activesprites:
        #print("drawing sprite:" + item)
    test.frame_render()
    apple.frame_render()
    pygame.display.update()
```